# Editing a file in a windows batch file using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I am attempting to edit a configuration file using a batch script. I looked around and I believe powershell is the way to go here. I have zero experience with powershell so I'm guessing that the syntax is what is causing me problems.

Here is what the file looks like now (This section is located in the middle of the file)

```
    <!--add key="MinNumCycles" value="25"/-->
    <!--add key="MaxNumCycles" value="40"/-->
```

Here's what I want it to look like

```
    <!--add key="MinNumCycles" value="25"/-->
    <!--add key="MaxNumCycles" value="40"/-->

    <!--RerunMode: 1 write to DB, 2 write to DB and add to RUN export/-->
    <add key="RerunMode" value="0"/>
```

Here's what I'm trying to do in my batch file that I need help with

```
SET pattern=<!--add key="MaxNumCycles" value="40"/-->
SET textToAdd1=<!--RerunMode: 1 write to DB, 2 write to DB and add to RUN export/-->
SET textToAdd2=<add key="RerunMode" value="0"/>
SET filename=Software.exe.config

powershell -Command "(gc %filename%) -replace "%pattern%", "$&`n`n%textToAdd1%"'n"%textToAdd2%" | sc %filename%"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pattern='<!--add key="MaxNumCycles" value="40"/-->'
$textToAdd = $pattern + '

    <!--RerunMode: 1 write to DB, 2 write to DB and add to RUN export/-->
    <add key="RerunMode" value="0"/>'

$filename = "Software.exe.config"

([IO.File]::ReadAllText($filename).Replace($pattern,$textToAdd) | Set-Content $filename -Force
```

Here's how I would replicate the batch file in all Powershell, personally.

1. The way your Powershell command did the replace will expect RegEx and your pattern would not match the way you expected it to. It would match it as if it were a RegEx pattern and not match the exact string like you had typed. If you use the .NET string method `.Replace()`, it only looks for exact strings.
2. `$textToAdd` contains the fully formatted final result, including the string we were searching for (both the beginning and end result have the string, this allows us to keep it there) as well as the concatenated addition. Per your description, the string marker is in the middle of the log, so this will allow it to just make those updates and re-save the log in it's entirety.

Comment: I get "Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'Replace'. How do you run this? I am just doing `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File script.ps1`

Comment: for the `$filename`, are you using the full path to the file you want to update, by chance? your call to run the script is good, the error being hit confirms it

Comment: I tested it on my machine and everything worked fine... what version of Powershell are you using? You can run `$PSVersionTable` to check

Comment: Im on version 2.0

Comment: Alright I figured it out. I changed `(Get-Content $filename)` to `[IO.File]::ReadAllText$filename)`

Comment: Awesome! Updated my answer to change the `Get-Content` part to `[IO.File]::ReadAllText($filename)`

Answer (score 0):

From the PowerShell command line, this would work (assuming your existing contents are in conf.bat):

```
$content = Get-Content -Path 'C:\path\to\Software.exe.config'
$content += "`r`n"
$content += '<!--RerunMode: 1 write to DB, 2 write to DB and add to RUN export/-->'
$content += '<add key="RerunMode" value="0"/>'
Set-Content -Value $content -Path 'C:\path\to\Software.exe.config'
```

You could save this as a script, and run it using:

```
powershell.exe -File script.ps1
```

Comment: `-Path "conf.bat"` should probably be `-Path "software.exe.config"` in both the `Get-Content` and `Set-Content` lines - or better still, make the file name a replaceable parameter.

Comment: Good call. Added.

Comment: Would this work in the middle of the file? I should have specified that the section I'm working with is not at the end of the file

Comment: This will take the existing content of the file, append new lines, and then overwrite the file. It doesn't care (so to speak) about a "middle". Please update your original question if this is what you require - and, please provide an example of what you require at the end :)

Comment: Updated. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

```
SET $pattern= '<!--add key="MaxNumCycles" value="40"/-->'
SET $textToAdd1='<!--RerunMode: 1 write to DB, 2 write to DB and add to 
RUN export/-->'
SET $textToAdd2='<add key="RerunMode" value="0"/>'
SET $filename='Software.exe.config'

(Get-Content $filename) -replace pattern, '`n' $textToAdd1 '`n' $textToAdd2 | Set-Content $filename
```

Similar to Robin's answer just another script you could run. He beat me to the punch :)

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. I am running like this